# KnockoutJS - observable object is undefined?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm still new to Knockout so I'm hoping someone would be able to help me with this.

This is my view model:

```
baseModel = {
    logged_in : ko.observable(),
    alerts : ko.observableArray(),
    errors: ko.observable()
};
```

And in my HTML I have:

`<span data-bind="text: ($root.errors['myerror1'] === undefined)? 'undefined':$root.errors['myerror1']"></span>`

I'm hoping to pull in arbitrary objects via AJAX and assigning it to my .errors property. For example, when my response is such:

`Object {myerror1: "password is wrong", error2: "something else is wrong"}`

I expect it to show the error in my `span` when I do the following in my AJAX success callback:

```
if( response.errors !== undefined )
     baseModel.errors = ko.mapping.fromJS(response.errors, {}, baseModel.errors);
```

OR,

```
if( response.errors !== undefined )
     baseModel.errors = response.errors;
```

Neither shows the `myerror1` that I bound in the HTML. I could probably be doing many things wrong here. I'm not sure what's wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to update the `errors` observable with a new value, you shouldn't set it using `=`, but call it passing the new value as parameter:

```
baseModel.errors({myerror1: "password is wrong", error2: "something else is wrong"});
```

**Update:** I spotted two additional problems with your code:

1. `errors` start as `undefined`; better set it to an empty object, so there won't be an error when the bindings are first evaluated:

   ```
   errors: ko.observable({})
   ```
2. If you want the value from `errors` inside an expression in `data-bind`, you should "call" it to get its value - instead of using it directly:

   ```
   <span data-bind="text: ($root.errors()['myerror1'] === undefined)?
   'undefined':$root.errors()['myerror1']"></span>
   ```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/AETWV/).

Comment: Tried this. Still getting `undefined` where the error text should be. This is because `$root.errors['myerror1'] === undefined` is returning `true`?

Comment: @user1077213 Apparently, when using a value in an expression you must get its value explicitly (using `errors()`). I hadn't noticed that at first. See the updated answer.